# round GETDATE (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a function which is working fine in MySQL

```
round((now()-ts/60) as tdiff
```

(round the result of subtracting the current datetime from ts (also a datetime) divided by 60)

Attempting (and failing) to convert this for SQL Server.

Tried -

```
round((GETDATE()-ts/60) as tdiff
```

but that results in round function requires 2 or 3 parameters (which to me it does), so modified to -

```
round((GETDATE()-ts/60,0) as tdiff
```

but that results in the datatypes (GETDATE and ts) are incompatible in the subtract operator.

So then I attempted to cast both GETDATE and ts as date and that made no difference.

ts is a conventional datetime i.e. 
2918-04-20  11:05:09 and I assumed GETDATE returned the same format.

As an example if GETDATE is today and ts is 2018-04-20 11:05:09 then tdiff is
6850891 (round effectively removes the dashes and colons and concatenates the datetime producing 20180420110509 for 2018-04-20 11:05:09 and 20180831164000 for 2018-08-31 16:40:00 and then divides by 60 to get 6850891.

Is there a remedy for this?

Regards, Ralph

Comment: To do date math you need to use DATEADD. I can't wrap my head around what your division is trying to do though. That to me makes no sense logically. What is August 30 divided by 60 supposed to return? Maybe you want DATEDIFF(day, getdate(), td) / 60?

Comment: Are you just trying to find the time difference between ts and now in seconds or minutes?

Comment: @Ralph . . . Please explain what you want to do.  Examples really help.

Comment: Hello Gordon, I have edited my original post to show the required calculation.

Answer (score 2):

`GETDATE()`, as per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/getdate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), returns a `datetime`. A `datetime` is accurate to 1/300 of a second, and it's accuracy cannot be changed.

If you want the time accurate to a second, you need to convert to a `datetime2(0)`:

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime2(0),GETDATE());
```

Also, however, don't use syntax like `GETDATE()-ts`. use the functions [`DATEADD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/DATEADD-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [`DATEDIFF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/DATEDIFF-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for date maths.

I've no idea what `GETDATE()-ts/60` is trying to acheive. Perhaps the number of minutes between the 2? `DATEDIFF` counts the "ticks" between 2 dates/times, thus `DATEDIFF(MINUTE,'00:00:59','00:01:00')` would return `1`, despite there only being 1 second between the 2 times. This is because the minute value has "ticked" once (from 0 to 1). Therefore you might want to use `DATEDIFF(SECOND,'00:00:59','00:01:00') / 60`. This would return 0, as `1 / 60` in integer math is 0 (as is `59 / 60`).

Comment: Thanks Lamu, though the result is still "round requires 2 arguments" (round is used so a datetime effectively becomes an integer so 60 can be subtracted)

Comment: @Ralph you shouldn't be using `ROUND({Some Datetime value},2)` in the first place. `ROUND` is for numbers, not dates.

Comment: True, but round is a perfect way (in my opinion) to concatenate a datetime to a numerical value so calcs can be performed resulting in integer results.

Comment: @Ralph Again, why are you combining dates and numerics? As I said **don't** use expressions like `GETDATE() -1`, use `DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE())`. Yes, that works on a `datetime`, because it's stored as decimal value from '19000101` (which is 0), but that's it. It doesn't work on  `date`, datetime2`, `datetimeoffset`, because dates are **not** numbers, they're dates and times.

Comment: Because some reports use 'response times' (i.e. how long it took a person to acknowledge an alert) and round makes that calculation very straightforward  in MySQL (unlike SQL Server which is on the point of being abandoned because there are so many 'incompatible' commands)

Comment: @Ralph sounds like you're trying to use SQL Server as if it was MySQL. It isn't. They're similar, but not the same. Just like OS X and Windows 10, or Excel and LibreOffice Calc.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use the DATEDIFF function:

```
DATEDIFF ( datepart , startdate , enddate ) 
DATEDIFF ( second, ts, GETDATE()) 
DATEDIFF ( second, ts, GETDATE()) 
DATEDIFF ( minute, ts, GETDATE()) 
DATEDIFF ( hour, ts, GETDATE())
```

The first argument tells it which increment of time to return.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to find the difference between two values, then use [`datediff()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).  For instance:

```
select datediff(day, getdate(), ts)
```

gets the difference in days.

`date_diff()` or a related function would also be the right approach in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

sorry, I don't know if I have understand the question, you need to do date-date/60 and round the result?

In this case you have to change the minus ("-") with the DATEDIFF("Type return example DAYS", GETDATE(), ts).

So you will have ROUND((DATEDIFF(DAY,GETDATE(),ts)/60,0)

Please try and let me know if it will works for you

Bye

Comment: Thanks Dona, though this returns 'An expression of non boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected neat ',''